# Trying to build a model to link GDP growth of a country to prices and production of oil and gas

Tags: r, linear-regression, economics, volatility

I'm trying to build a model which would link GDP growth to oil and gas prices. 
More specifically, I selected Canada's GDP and the WCS, WTI and Brent. 
However, importantly enough, WCS is a commodity that is highly correlated to WTI already, so maybe we could just use its volatility. 
Sorry, I am fairly new to R, programming and stats in general, I've been trying to learn everything at the same time, and enjoying the struggle so far !

## The dateset:

```
> growth_rate <- function(x)(x/lag(x)-1)*100 
> df$Ggdp <- growth_rate(df$GDP)
> df
             GDP    wti  brent    wcs prod         Ggdp
May 2008 1625281 127.35 127.85 102.95 3178           NA
Jun 2008 1630757 139.96 138.40 122.00 3199  0.336926353
Jul 2008 1640312 124.17 124.10 104.33 3423  0.585924206
Aug 2008 1637072 115.55 113.49  94.81 3434 -0.197523398
Sep 2008 1635731 100.70  93.52  80.99 3304 -0.081914540
Oct 2008 1635860  68.10  60.00  46.31 3346  0.007886382
Nov 2008 1617639  55.21  47.72  37.93 3455 -1.113848373
Dec 2008 1596396  44.60  35.82  35.20 3393 -1.313210179
Jan 2009 1582918  41.73  44.17  31.93 3407 -0.844276733
Feb 2009 1576917  44.15  44.41  38.76 3487 -0.379109973
Mar 2009 1566404  49.64  46.13  43.31 3361 -0.666680618
Apr 2009 1561546  50.35  50.30  41.87 3115 -0.310137104
May 2009 1558576  66.31  64.98  57.86 3066 -0.190196126
Jun 2009 1558940  69.82  68.11  59.09 3223  0.023354652
Jul 2009 1563453  69.26  70.08  58.20 3422  0.289491578
Aug 2009 1565190  69.97  69.02  59.46 3333  0.111100238
Sep 2009 1575366  70.46  65.82  59.56 3276  0.650144711
Oct 2009 1577786  77.04  74.91  63.35 3343  0.153615096
Nov 2009 1587571  77.19  77.77  66.28 3480  0.620172824
Dec 2009 1591336  79.39  77.91  71.86 3322  0.237154748
Jan 2010 1601650  72.85  71.20  64.59 3238  0.648134649
Feb 2010 1606768  79.72  76.36  69.41 3318  0.319545469
Mar 2010 1614763  83.45  80.37  70.46 3349  0.497582725
Apr 2010 1613317  86.07  86.19  71.50 3388 -0.089548745
May 2010 1622249  74.00  73.00  61.57 3437  0.553641969
Jun 2010 1625907  75.59  74.94  62.93 3448  0.225489429
Jul 2010 1626913  78.85  77.50  64.30 3457  0.061873158
Aug 2010 1632145  71.93  75.51  51.17 3517  0.321590644
Sep 2010 1632415  79.95  80.77  63.62 3327  0.016542648
Oct 2010 1639515  81.45  82.47  65.08 3417  0.434938419
Nov 2010 1644860  84.12  86.02  69.66 3667  0.326011046
Dec 2010 1656532  91.38  93.23  71.38 3727  0.709604465
Jan 2011 1661194  90.99  98.97  71.69 3588  0.281431328
Feb 2011 1660783  97.10 112.27  72.97 3478 -0.024741240
Mar 2011 1666300 106.19 116.94  91.22 3579  0.332192707
Apr 2011 1668525 113.39 126.59  98.18 3549  0.133529376
May 2011 1664526 102.70 117.18  84.95 3217 -0.239672765
Jun 2011 1670263  95.30 111.71  74.92 3325  0.344662685
Jul 2011 1682272  95.68 115.93  77.70 3598  0.718988566
Aug 2011 1691568  88.81 116.48  77.06 3748  0.552586027
Sep 2011 1694178  78.93 105.42  68.70 3658  0.154294714
Oct 2011 1694510  93.19 108.43  81.69 3737  0.019596524
Nov 2011 1695778 100.36 111.22  88.76 3738  0.074829892
Dec 2011 1703622  98.83 108.09  82.68 3930  0.462560547
Jan 2012 1702562  98.46 110.26  71.48 3885 -0.062220375
Feb 2012 1698087 107.08 122.23  73.82 4056 -0.262839180
Mar 2012 1702254 103.03 123.41  79.02 3794  0.245393787
Apr 2012 1708046 104.89 118.66  90.02 3922  0.340254745
May 2012 1710720  86.52 103.86  67.03 3692  0.156553161
Jun 2012 1711557  85.04  94.17  57.96 3601  0.048926768
Jul 2012 1714908  88.08 105.93  65.31 3781  0.195786643
Aug 2012 1712687  96.47 113.93  80.47 3761 -0.129511321
Sep 2012 1712525  92.18 111.36  80.69 3678 -0.009458821
Oct 2012 1711819  86.23 109.89  56.74 3900 -0.041225676
Nov 2012 1720035  88.54 110.84  59.41 4008  0.479957285
Dec 2012 1719947  91.83 110.80  58.82 4194 -0.005116175
Jan 2013 1728397  97.65 115.55  65.99 4116  0.491294208
Feb 2013 1736155  92.03 112.20  66.55 4027  0.448855211
Mar 2013 1743151  97.24 108.46  82.88 4188  0.402959413
Apr 2013 1745096  93.22 101.53  76.21 3986  0.111579548
May 2013 1749713  91.93 100.43  72.96 3715  0.264569972
Jun 2013 1742837  96.36 102.49  82.31 3875 -0.392978734
Jul 2013 1752313 105.10 107.89  84.53 4035  0.543711202
Aug 2013 1760601 107.98 115.97  83.65 4210  0.472974862
Sep 2013 1766363 102.36 107.85  70.43 4071  0.327274607
Oct 2013 1776243  96.29 107.53  58.88 4064  0.559341426
Nov 2013 1778904  92.55 111.07  63.22 4247  0.149810583
Dec 2013 1770301  98.17 109.95  75.55 4333 -0.483612382
Jan 2014 1775276  97.55 108.16  78.99 4379  0.281025656
Feb 2014 1785782 102.88 108.98  77.34 4410  0.591795304
Mar 2014 1787878 101.57 105.95  81.57 4468  0.117371549
Apr 2014 1794046 100.07 108.63  80.99 4341  0.344989983
May 2014 1800584 103.40 109.21  83.71 4182  0.364427668
Jun 2014 1805647 106.07 111.03  84.37 4304  0.281186548
Jul 2014 1806714  98.23 104.94  76.47 4356  0.059092392
Aug 2014 1803892  97.86 101.12  79.21 4295 -0.156195170
Sep 2014 1815108  91.17  94.67  76.91 4333  0.621766713
Oct 2014 1822608  80.53  84.17  65.29 4515  0.413198553
Nov 2014 1821315  65.94  71.89  48.40 4522 -0.070942298
Dec 2014 1824784  53.45  55.27  37.27 4628  0.190466778
Jan 2015 1818224  47.79  47.52  35.24 4702 -0.359494603
Feb 2015 1817046  49.84  61.89  36.01 4743 -0.064788497
Mar 2015 1815416  47.72  53.69  35.05 4632 -0.089706039
Apr 2015 1813895  59.62  63.90  49.28 4300 -0.083782450
May 2015 1810301  60.25  63.16  52.45 3999 -0.198137158
Jun 2015 1817154  59.48  60.31  47.47 4204  0.378555831
Jul 2015 1824302  47.11  53.29  31.12 4618  0.393362368
Aug 2015 1828312  49.20  47.97  34.55 4759  0.219810097
Sep 2015 1820148  45.06  47.29  31.04 4299 -0.446532102
Oct 2015 1821259  46.60  48.00  31.39 4419  0.061038992
Nov 2015 1825481  40.43  43.73  27.65 4686  0.231817660
Dec 2015 1828773  37.13  36.61  23.79 4773  0.180336032
Jan 2016 1838454  33.66  33.14  18.37 4817  0.529371333
Feb 2016 1835456  32.74  35.92  21.15 4737 -0.163071798
Mar 2016 1830147  36.94  36.75  25.19 4657 -0.289246923
Apr 2016 1831421  45.98  45.64  32.57 4319  0.069611895
May 2016 1816590  49.10  49.26  37.35 3681 -0.809808340
Jun 2016 1825265  48.27  48.05  34.53 3982  0.477543089
Jul 2016 1837864  41.54  40.76  26.85 4607  0.690255935
Aug 2016 1840817  44.68  47.94  30.45 4745  0.160675654
Sep 2016 1849536  47.72  48.24  34.24 4749  0.473648385
Oct 2016 1849617  46.83  46.20  32.51 4813  0.004379477
Nov 2016 1856460  49.41  47.95  33.84 5135  0.369968485
Dec 2016 1863740  53.75  54.96  37.62 4918  0.392144188
Jan 2017 1875014  52.75  55.25  39.56 5120  0.604912702
Feb 2017 1878894  54.00  53.36  40.11 5140  0.206931788
Mar 2017 1886240  50.54  52.20  39.20 4910  0.390974690
Apr 2017 1893750  49.31  49.46  40.08 4500  0.398146577
May 2017 1900669  48.29  49.40  38.62 4633  0.365359736
Jun 2017 1905701  46.02  47.08  36.24 4686  0.264748886
Jul 2017 1910171  50.21  51.99  40.02 4963  0.234559356
Aug 2017 1907877  47.26  52.69  35.98 5117 -0.120093960
Sep 2017 1913738  51.67  57.02  40.42 4933  0.307200097
Oct 2017 1915700  54.36  61.35  41.23 4945  0.102521871
Nov 2017 1924355  57.40  63.53  40.30 5273  0.451793078
Dec 2017 1929676  60.46  66.73  34.42 5350  0.276508233
Jan 2018 1926871  64.82  67.78  35.73 5234 -0.145361190
Feb 2018 1934832  61.43  66.08  36.39 5395  0.413156875
Mar 2018 1940870  64.87  69.02  42.94 5434  0.312068438
Apr 2018 1939261  68.56  75.92  51.97 5068 -0.082900967
May 2018 1948011  66.98  76.45  42.04 5219  0.451202804
Jun 2018 1949676  74.13  77.44  53.15 5147  0.085471797
Jul 2018 1956404  69.88  74.16  39.76 5361  0.345082978
Aug 2018 1959899  69.84  76.94  42.55 5647  0.178644084
Sep 2018 1959168  73.16  82.72  38.35 5224 -0.037297840
Oct 2018 1964180  65.31  74.84  22.31 5540  0.255822880
Nov 2018 1957539  50.78  57.71  21.93 5637 -0.338105469
Dec 2018 1958332  45.15  50.57  29.66 5667  0.040510049
Jan 2019 1959350  53.84  62.46  44.29 5392  0.051983014
Feb 2019 1953947  57.21  65.03  45.22 5413 -0.275754715
Mar 2019 1969024  60.19  67.93  50.86 5498  0.771617654
Apr 2019 1976666  63.83  72.19  50.61 5542  0.388111064
May 2019 1981503  53.49  66.78  36.77 5367  0.244704973
Jun 2019 1986929  58.20  67.52  44.73 5504  0.273832540
Jul 2019 1984618  58.53  64.07  45.20 5500 -0.116310145
Aug 2019 1986990  55.07  61.04  43.51 5527  0.119519222
Sep 2019 1986480  54.09  60.99  41.45 5384 -0.025666964
Oct 2019 1985712  54.02  59.30  35.02 5455 -0.038661351
Nov 2019 1986851  58.12  64.50  36.10 5648  0.057359778
Dec 2019 1992292  61.14  67.77  38.57 5761  0.273850430
Jan 2020 1994590  51.58  57.77  30.73 5688  0.115344538
```

## The attempted model we are trying to build

```
**First the correlation table**
```

```
             GDP        wti      brent        wcs       prod Ggdp
GDP    1.0000000 -0.4562972 -0.3658848 -0.5542391  0.9658432   NA
wti   -0.4562972  1.0000000  0.9694464  0.9549166 -0.5033770   NA
brent -0.3658848  0.9694464  1.0000000  0.9049227 -0.4165634   NA
wcs   -0.5542391  0.9549166  0.9049227  1.0000000 -0.6064784   NA
prod   0.9658432 -0.5033770 -0.4165634 -0.6064784  1.0000000   NA
Ggdp          NA         NA         NA         NA         NA    1
```

And then the models:

```
> m1=lm(ldf$GDP ~ ldf$brent +ldf$wcs, data=ldf)
> summary(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = ldf$GDP ~ ldf$brent + ldf$wcs, data = ldf)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.098497 -0.041036  0.001208  0.041365  0.107232 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 14.66902    0.06892 212.851  < 2e-16 ***
ldf$brent    0.14656    0.03590   4.082 9.17e-05 ***
ldf$wcs     -0.22944    0.03084  -7.440 4.07e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0512 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4918,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4813 
F-statistic: 46.93 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 5.531e-15

> 
> m2=lm(ldf$GDP ~ ldf$wcs+lag(ldf$wcs,4)+ldf$wti,data=ldf)
> summary(m2)

Call:
lm(formula = ldf$GDP ~ ldf$wcs + lag(ldf$wcs, 4) + ldf$wti, data = ldf)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.115679 -0.037848  0.007694  0.039826  0.104736 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     14.75017    0.08422 175.128  < 2e-16 ***
ldf$wcs         -0.16780    0.03992  -4.204 6.08e-05 ***
lag(ldf$wcs, 4) -0.07080    0.01901  -3.725 0.000337 ***
ldf$wti          0.13933    0.05063   2.752 0.007131 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.04976 on 92 degrees of freedom
  (4 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.5049,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4887 
F-statistic: 31.27 on 3 and 92 DF,  p-value: 5.019e-14

> 
> m3=lm(ldf$prod ~ ldf$wcs +lag(ldf$wcs,4), data=ldf)
> summary(m3)

Call:
lm(formula = ldf$prod ~ ldf$wcs + lag(ldf$wcs, 4), data = ldf)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.26768 -0.09780  0.01005  0.11000  0.20707 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      9.69410    0.14113  68.689  < 2e-16 ***
ldf$wcs         -0.20093    0.04733  -4.246 5.16e-05 ***
lag(ldf$wcs, 4) -0.13319    0.04638  -2.872  0.00505 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1236 on 93 degrees of freedom
  (4 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.4903,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4793 
F-statistic: 44.72 on 2 and 93 DF,  p-value: 2.465e-14

> 
> df$growgdp=growth_rate(df$GDP)
```

The regressions seem a bit okay, but the problem is that the explained variables and explanatory variables are correlated. Variables themselves are col-linear (specifically WCS and WTI).

Also, I worked on a volatility analysis few days back. The idea here is to build a model that tracks the impact of the volatility of WCS and shows its impact on its price and the relative price of WTI. I am trying to go further. More specifically, I am trying to see if there is any link between the price volatility and the GDP growth.

Could you help ?

## Volatility Analysis

```
rbrent=na.omit(diff(log(x[,1])))
rwcss=na.omit(diff(log(x[,2])))
rspread=na.omit(diff(log(x[,3])))

vrbrent=rollapply(rbrent, width = 22, FUN = sd, fill=NA)*sqrt(252)
autoplot(vrbrent)

vrwcss=rollapply(rwcss,width = 22,FUN=sd,fill=NA)*sqrt(252)
autoplot(vrwcss)

vrspread=rollapply(rspread,width=22,FUN=sd,fill=NA)*sqrt(252)
autoplot(vrspread)

total=na.omit(cbind(vrbrent,vrwcss,vrspread))
autoplot(total)

max(total[,1:3])



info=rbind(apply(total,2,max),apply(total,2,min))
rownames(info)=c("max","min")
info



# Regression analysis 

pairs(coredata(total))


correl1= lm(vrwcss ~vrbrent)
vcov(correl1)

correl1

plot(x=coredata(vrbrent), y=coredata(vrwcss), type="p")
abline(correl1$coefficients[1]   ,correl1$coefficients[2])
```

Comment: I'm having trouble finding an actual question. Are you having some technical difficulty that is keeping you from running a particular test?

Comment: I am trying to figure out the best way to conduct this regression given that I have multi-colinearity.